# User has access to page via Active Directory group they aren't in

Tags: permissions

I have an Active Directory Group 'GROUPA' that contains Person1 and Person2 I also have Person3 who is not in that group.

I create a sharepoint page, and in that page I set the page permissions to give that group Full Control.

If I then run a check Permissions on that page for Person 3 it states that they have full control of that page given through GROUPA, although they are not in GROUPA.

The annoying thing is, this setup worked 3 weeks ago, and is now giving everyone access to everything via Active Directory Groups they aren't actually part of.

I am a complete Sharepoint Newbie and have been going round in circles checking Site Collections etc but getting nowhere, if I remove GROUPA from having Access Peron3 looses Access so I am fairly confident this is where my issue is, I just don't know why.

Comment: What permissions do you have set on the site itself? Are you breaking inheritance on the page?

Comment: I am breaking inheritance as the main page I need every one to see and then sub pages are based on certain users/groups.  So the main access is Everyone Read and the sub page is GroupA Read person3 is not in GroupA

Comment: When you look at site permissions, do you see person 3 listed? Is person 3 listed as a site collection administrator maybe?

Comment: It turned out not to be a sharepoint issue at all and ultimately is was because GroupB had been made and GroupA along with other Groups that person3 was in were meant to be put into Group B, unfortunately all the Groups were Put in B and then B was put in A, so person3 was indirectly in GroupA via GroupB hence they were not showing as in GroupA. It was like looking for a needle in a haystack, thanks for the help though.

Comment: Were these security groups in AD???

Comment: yes they were AD groups